# Finder copies files in two steps and does it as a transaction

Tags: macos, finder, nas, file-transfer, smb

I need to organize thousands of files between different locations and there is an unpleasant issue with file copying from a local computer to a NAS. The problem is that Finder copies large bunch of files in two steps. In the first step it creates all those files in the destination location for a some reason, they are all empty there. It's a lengthy process. In the second step Finder actually starts copying content. It takes even more time. It looks like a transaction. Finder copies all files or nothing. But I don't need a transaction. In my opinion, a more common way is to copy files sequentially, one by one (or in a small groups). It's faster, it allows user to cancel copying in any time and prevents him from losing progress in operation.
Is there any way to prevent Finder from doing such a transactionality and make it copy files sequentially in one step?

Local computer: MacBook Pro, OS X 10.10.4 (Yosemite).
NAS: homebuilt server, FreeBSD 10.1 and Samba 4.2

ps: I do know about the alternative ways to copy files (console, file managers). My question is about the Finder and OS X behavior.

Comment: I'm guessing the copy behaviour may depend on the filesystems and/or network protocols in use. What filesystem is on the NAS, and is it connected by SMB, AFP, NFS...?

Answer (score 1):

From many years of experience* with transferring sets of many hundreds of thousands of files (with tens of thousands of nested folders,) the safest and quickest methods *avoid* the Finder completely and uses the console commands.

Don't beat your head against the wall - Finder just won't do it satisfactorily. Investigate `rsync` as a possible method for transfer.

*manual backups of FirstClass PostOffice directories.